# Update many-to-many relationship

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

I have 2 entity User and Role that are mapped like:

```
accountSet.HasMany(x => x.Roles).WithMany(x => x.Users).Map(t =>
      {
        t.ToTable("UserRole");
        t.MapLeftKey("UserId");
        t.MapRightKey("RoleId");
      });
```

I'm trying to update User (by adding new UserRole)

```
 var rolesForUser = UnitOfWork.UserRoleService.FindEntitiesByFilter(...);
user.Roles.Clear();

    foreach (var role in rolesForUser)
              user.Roles.Add(role)
```

In service:

```
 AttachCollections(entity);
 _entityRepository.Update(entity);
```

AttachCollections:

```
private void AttachCollections(EntityBase entity)
    {
      var result = new List<IEnumerable<EntityBase>>();
      foreach (var prop in entity.GetType().GetProperties())
      {
        if (typeof(IEnumerable<EntityBase>).IsAssignableFrom(prop.PropertyType))
        {
          var get = prop.GetGetMethod();
          if (!get.IsStatic && get.GetParameters().Length == 0 && get.IsVirtual)
          {
            var enumerable = (IEnumerable<EntityBase>)get.Invoke(entity, null);
            if (enumerable != null) result.Add(enumerable);
          }
        }
      }
      foreach (var collection in result)
      {
          foreach (var r in collection)
          {

            var collectionType = r.GetType();/
            _dbContext.Set(collectionType).Attach(r);
          }
      }
    }


...UnitOfWork.Commit()
```

And I got error "AcceptChanges cannot continue because the object's key values conflict with another object in the ObjectStateManager. Make sure that the key values are unique before calling AcceptChanges.

If I remove ApplyCollection I got error that cannot insert duplicate User with id.
It seems that UserRole are marked as Added state. If change this state then Users (which User role contains) marked as added as well.

Comment: It was sorted out.It turned out that I used entities which were retrieved from different context. Here is place:UnitOfWork.UserRoleService.FindEntitiesByFilter(...)